# How can I get a column out of another string column with any special character removed in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to create a table column from another without special characters?

I would like to look up name of cities in a column. In some cases (french and italian cities) I don't get matched due to special characters like dashes and accents.
Therefore I would like to "transform" this column into one without any special characters.
The so called Umlauts should get mapped like this ö=> oe, ü=> ue etc...

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think you'll need to explain what you're hoping to do a lot more clearly.  What constitutes a special character?  Are you hoping to use a trigger to remove white space and punctuation from a string to simplify comparisons, or something like that?

Comment: I need to resolve names of cities and in France or Italy they oftentimes have special characters like dashes or accents. So in order to search for those cities I would assume that striping the string might lead to better results?!

Comment: Please update the question rather than add comments (you've been around SO long enough to know better than that).  Your question should outline your scenario.  Presumably, then, your definition of special character is 'accented characters' and they should be mapped to unaccented ASCII.  What do you plan to do for ß U+00DF, LATIN  SMALL LETTER SHARP S, Eszett?  Do you plan to transliterate ö U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS to 'o' or 'oe'?  Etc.

Comment: You could create a view that uses the `unaccent` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but what about dashes etc. ?

Comment: fulltext search removes dashes etc anyway, but it sounds like you don't want fulltext search. Unaccent doesn't "normalize" chars how you want, it just strips accents. Check out `share/tsearch_data/unaccent.rules` . You can however create your own filter dictionary modeled on unaccent's (see the documentation) that contains the mappings you want for your language. Remember that the decompositions of diacritic accented characters differ from language to language. For hyphens etc I'd just use a regexp. So: probably custom unaccent dictionary + regexp is your best bet.